# Merge tags driver, drivers, and device-driver on SU

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

This is a simple retag request:

Merge [driver](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/driver), [drivers](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/drivers), and [device-driver](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/device-driver).

[driver](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/driver) is the most common, so they should probably be merged into that.

Actually, as a few people have pointed out, [drivers](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/drivers) is probably more intuitive, so that may make more sense.

Answer (score 4):

[driver](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/driver) sounds less intuitive than [drivers](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/drivers). Stilted even, like it was some kind of attempt at keeping things in singular fashion as opposed to plural.

When you're talking about [drivers], you're talking about [drivers]. Can't see it being [driver].

[device-driver](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/device-driver) seems way superfluous.

Comment: +1 I guess `drivers` is more intuitive, but I simply suggested `driver` because it is more common. I really don't think it matters that much (and Google is smart enough not to care).

Comment: Do you have any more arguments to back up your logic aside from "sounds more intuitive"?

Comment: Nope. Other than conservations wherein it's always been noted as "drivers" instead of "driver".

Comment: To be clear: you're proposing changing the tag to "driver", which is used 101 times, to "drivers", which is used 51 times, based on some personal conversations you've had with other people.  I can't really say I favor this kind of prescriptive change.

Comment: Throwing down some support on the plural version based on anecdotal experience, yes.

Comment: While it's possible that someone has been busily retagging, your anecdotal evidence is clearly outweighed (2 to 1) by the present statistics.  In the face of such evidence, the onus is on you to provide a more solid case as to why the (vast) minority should prevail here.

Comment: @Eric, Presumably the majority of people that used [driver] picked that because it was displayed first by the auto-complete.  Just because it is popular doesn't make it right or preferred.

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised that driver is the most common. I would assume that "drivers" would be the first thing thought of when trying to do a search. Maybe that is just me.

Comment: I blame the auto-complete.

Answer (score 0):

I've now finished this up by merging [device-driver](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/device-driver) → [drivers](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/drivers)